# Expansion of an arbitrary density matrix in terms of coherent states?

Tags: hilbert-space, density-operator, coherent-states

It is well-known that any pure state can be expanded in terms of coherent states namely
$$\left|\psi\right>=\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2\alpha\left<\alpha|\psi\right>\left|\alpha\right>$$ due to completeness property of coherent states. How can we use this property to write down any density matrix $\rho$ in terms of coherent states.

Is this appraoch right? any density matrix $\rho$ can be written as $\int p_{\left|\psi\right>}\left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right| d\psi$. Therefore we need to just substitute $\left|\psi\right>$ in terms of coherent states?!

Comment: You might probably want to look into phase space distribution functions? They come with a huge menu card. For example Glauber-Sudarshan P-function is apt to get the final representation you are after.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that gives the answer to my question. How about for two mode systems? lets say we have a completness relation for two mode states, how can we use that completeness relation to write down any state?

Comment: Phase space distribution functions and expansion of wavefunction in terms of over-complete coherent state basis are not specific for single mode case.