# Computing ${\rm tr}\left[\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{D}(\alpha)\right]$

Tags: operators, harmonic-oscillator

I'm having some trouble computing ${\rm tr}\left[\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{D}(\alpha)\right]$ where $\hat{D}(\alpha)$ is the [displacement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator).

I tried doing this using the number state basis, which allows us to write the trace of an operator $\hat{A}$ as
$${\rm tr}\left(\hat{A}\right) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \langle n |\hat{A} | n \rangle $$
Using that $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ sends $|n \rangle \mapsto n |n \rangle$, I got that
$${\rm tr}\left[\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{D}(\alpha)\right]= \sum_{n \geq 0} n \langle n |\hat{D}(\alpha) | n \rangle,$$
but am unable to continue from here. I was wondering if someone could direct me to another approach or a reference where this is worked out. (For context, I actually want to compute the Wigner function of $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$.)

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345543/completeness-relation-of-coherent-spaces).

Comment: You know the [resolution of the identity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452488/expansion-of-an-arbitrary-density-matrix-in-terms-of-coherent-states) in terms of coherent states, and the action of *D*  on them, and the projection of number states on them, so...

Comment: Oh, I can maybe use the resolution of the identity to rewrite the number states in terms of coherent states. I'll try this and see if I can get something apparent.

Comment: So I wrote $|n \rangle$ as $\frac{1}{\pi} \int d^{2}\alpha \langle \alpha| n \rangle |\alpha \rangle$. Doing so and using that $D(\alpha)|\alpha \rangle = \alpha |\alpha \rangle$, I obtained that $\langle n | D(\alpha) |n \rangle = \frac{1}{\pi{n!}} \int d^{2}\alpha ( \alpha^{2n} e^{-1/2|\alpha|^{2}})$. So I guess I need to evaluate the last expression

Comment: Except D(α) *shifts the eigenvalue* of the coherent state it acts on!!

Comment: Oh whoops, what I wrote was badly off. Yes, we are considering a specific $\alpha$ here, not one that varies with the integral.....back to the drawing board......

Comment: I ended up getting $\langle n | D(\alpha) | n \rangle = \frac{1}{\pi} \int d^{2}\lambda e^{\lambda^{*}\alpha -\alpha^{*}\lambda} \langle n| \alpha + \lambda \rangle   \langle \lambda|n \rangle
$
and I think I can treat $\langle n| \alpha + \lambda \rangle$ as a Dirac mass centered at $\lambda = n-\alpha$....